# LinQ - Error when trying to order by child property

Tags: linq, .net-core

I'm trying to get a List of object that includes another list of childs with LinQ.
I need to sort this object by parent order and then by childs order. 
This is my code:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Menus>> GetMenus(string modulo)
    {
        var result = this.context.Set<Menus>()
            .Include(det => det.MenusSub)
            .Where(e => e.Modulo.Equals(modulo))
            .OrderBy(s => s.Orden).ThenBy(s => s.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden));

        return await result.ToListAsync();
    }
```

The problem comes from the thenBy, because when executed this query return this error:

> "Message": "Failed to compare two elements in the array.",
>       "StackTrace": "   at System.Collections.Generic.GenericArraySortHelper`1.Sort(T[] keys, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   at System.Array.Sort[T](T[] array, Int32 index, Int32 length, IComparer`1 comparer)\r\n   at System.Linq.EnumerableSorter`1.Sort(TElement[] elements, Int32 count)\r\n   at System.Linq.OrderedEnumerable`1.GetEnumerator()+MoveNext()\r\n   at System.Linq.OrderedAsyncEnumerable`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.EntityQueryModelVisitor.AsyncSelectEnumerable`2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.SelectEnumerableAsyncIterator`2.MoveNextCore(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.AsyncIterator`1.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor`1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.Aggregate_[TSource,TAccumulate,TResult](IAsyncEnumerable`1 source, TAccumulate seed, Func`3 accumulator, Func`2 resultSelector, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n   at Ohmio.Data.MenusRepository.GetMenus(String modulo) in C:\Users\ericp\Documents\Mis Proyectos\Ohmio WEB\ohmio-web-server\OhmioData\Repositorios\MenusRepository.cs:line 42\r\n   at Ohmio.Servicios.MenusService.GetMenus(String modulo) in C:\Users\ericp\Documents\Mis Proyectos\Ohmio WEB\ohmio-web-server\OhmioServicios\MenusService.cs:line 26\r\n   at Ohmio.Api.Controladores.MenusController.GetMenus(String modulo) in C:\Users\ericp\Documents\Mis Proyectos\Ohmio WEB\ohmio-web-server\OhmioWEBAPINetCore\Controladores\MenusController.cs:line 26\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeNextActionFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Rethrow(ActionExecutedContext context)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(State& next, Scope& scope, Object& state, Boolean& isCompleted)\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()\r\n   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Internal.ResourceInvoker.InvokeNextExceptionFilterAsync()"

If I remove the thenBy statement, everything works fine.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: May be try `.OrderBy(s => s.Orden).ThenBy(s => s.MenusSub.Select(p => p.Orden))`

Comment: Thanks Mohsin, but no, i get the same error ""Failed to compare two elements in the array."

Comment: How can you sort by the results of `s.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden)` -- isn't it some kind of [`IOrderedQueryable<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.iorderedqueryable-1?view=netframework-4.8)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is that `s.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden)` is returning a collection of objects. Since your custom object probably doesn't implement `IComparable` and `IComparable<T>` it's throwing the exception you see, which makes sense because it doesn't know how to compare two instances of your `Menus` type. None of the collection types in .Net implement the `IComparable` interface either.

Instead, you'll need to remove the `ThenBy` and instead use a projection in your `return` statement. Like this:

```c#
return await result.Select(r =>
    new Menus
    {
        // Assign Menus properties
        MenusSub = r.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden)
    }).ToListAsync();
```

Or you can load the collection into memory with the parent sorted, then return the result with the children sorted:

```c#
foreach (var menu in result)
{
    menu.MenusSub = menu.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden);
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks Matt. I only need to modify your intruction to menu.MenusSub = menu.MenusSub.OrderBy(p => p.Orden).ToList();. Find out that net core Eager Loading using the .Include statement does not suppoort filtering or sortering on child collection property